# How to create title bar menu in Gnome shell from a Gtk Application

Tags: gtk, gnome, gnome-shell, gjs

Is is possible to create a title bar menu from inside a Gtk Application? And is it possible with C or Python or does one need to launch GJs and create the menu similar to a gnome shell extension?

The picture shows the menu I am talking about (in this case a gnome shell extension). I am not talking about the Application Menu (in the screenshot the 'Builder' menu), because that is only visible if the Gtk application has focus, but I want a menu that is always visible.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use a shell extension; sorry. Deploy it as part of your app and use DBus to communicate back and forth. I wouldn't know how to do this; sorry.

(Credits to aleb and TingPing for help thinking about this answer.)

Comment: Thank you. I think that will be helpful advice for people trying to migrate away from the Gnome Notification Area (currently at the bottom left). There are some programs that put a lot of menus there and it not really the best place to hide such menus.